# Выравнивание навигации по центру Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Всем привет. Решил ознакомиться с бутрапом и начал делать небольшой сайт. Наткнулся вроде на мелочь, но неприятно. Вообщем код навигационной панели:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

`ml-auto` для широких экранов выровнял навигацию по правому краю. В бургер меню при маленьких экранах она оказалась почему то слева. Добавил `text-center` и вроде выглядит неплохо. Но теперь решил добавить отступы между пунктами меню при большом экране.Кроме `margin/padding` не придумал как это можно сделать. Добавил, вроде не плохо, но теперь смотрю на бургер меню и по очевидным причинам там отступ слева тоже добавился и текст уже не в центре.Как можно по отдельности стилизовать навигацию для больших и маленьких экранов. Сори за воду, не знал как короче сформулировать.
Возможно и так понятно, но на всякий приложу фото.

[image: На широких экранах]

[image: на мобильных экранах]

Comment: `...style='text-align:center;'` ?

Comment: Пробовал, но `margin` не дает сдвинуться. В бутстрапе `text-center` наверное то же самое делает что и `text-align:center`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, * замените на числовой значение

```
position: relative;
left: *px;
right: *px;
margin:0px auto!important;
padding:0px!important
```

Comment: Чтобы left/right работали разве не должно быть position:absolute?

Comment: @Тимур не должно. Так работает

Comment: @Тимур relative  - расслабленно, то-бишь позиция не привязана и ею так же можно управлять